# need to connect to MS access database and populate them in mysql table automatically every 30 min

Tags: mysql, ms-access, auto-populate

I am developing a time sheets project, i am using mysql as database, i need to connect to MS access database and pull required data and sore it in mysql database. I have to do this automatically every 30 min. I was wondering if there is anyway i can do this using stored procedure or triggers. I am using java with spring,hibernate,and jsf in my application.

Thanks a lot for taking a look at my problem.

Please help i need to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something you'd use a cron for, you can write a Java application or PHP script that gets the data from your Access DB and stores it in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can add your Application or Script in Windows Tasks Manager (Run->Tasks)